# Global function for Meteor template helper

Tags: meteor

I have registered a global function like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('dialogBoxOptions', function (callbackFunctionName){
    return {
        callBack: callbackFunctionName
    };
});
```

but when I try to access it as below I get dialogBoxOptions is not defined

```
Template.myLlist.helpers({
    dOpt: dialogBoxOptions('dlgCB')
});
```

I have tried this as a global handlebars helper and a regular javascript function but get the same result.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't access handlebars helpers this way you can access them in the template:

```
<template name="myList">
     {{dialogBoxOptions.callback 'something'}}
</template>
```

If you want to access it in your helper like you are doing now you should register a global method instead. You could put this in a file like `/lib/helpers.js`

```
dialogBoxOptions = function (callbackFunctionName){
    return {
        callBack: callbackFunctionName
    };
}
```

Also if you want to make a global template helper, the syntax is now:

```
Template.registerHelper("dialogBoxOptions", function (param2) {
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I had tried a global javascript function but I think it was in the wrong location, putting in /lib seems to have done the trick. One note: it doesn't work when using "function dialogBoxOptions(callbackFunctionName)", I have to use your syntax - why would that be?

Comment: `function xx()` is variable scoped so it works but only in the file its defined in, likewise `var xx = function()` is also scoped to the file. Without the `var` keyword it is visible to all the files. `/lib` is loaded first so perhaps that why it worked after you moved it there

Comment: In this case, how would dialogBoxOptions gain access to, say, a Collection subscription within the Template instance?

Answer (score 13):

There is now a way to get access to the registered global helpers.

```
//Register the helper
UI.registerHelper("functionName", function (param1, param2) {
  return true;
});

//Use the helper elsewhere
var result = UI._globalHelpers('functionName')(param1, param2);
```

Comment: Isn't UI.registerHelper depreciated for Template.helpers?  What would be the syntax for accessing the Template.helpers in this case? Maybe Template._globalHelpers perhaps?

Comment: @Aaron: `Template.registerHelper` would be the correct method: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_registerhelper

Comment: @erb I'm now using the registerHelper(s). thank you. :)

Comment: Bit of a hack, but after `Template.registerHelper({...})`, you can get the function from `Blaze._globalHelpers['func_name']`.

Answer (score 8):

Use `Template.registerHelper(name, function)`
As shown in [Meteor Documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_registerhelper)

Answer (score 6):

In Meteor 1.0+ it looks like the syntax for creating a global helper is now:

```
Template.registerHelper('functionName',function(param1,param2){
  ... your code here ...
})
```

Then use it anywhere on the client with:

```
var result = Blaze._globalHelpers.functionName(param1, param2);
```

OTOH, the UI object doesn't appear in the current [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/) so I'm left wondering if this usage is blessed.