# Access Template.TemplateName.helpers from Template.helpers and vice versa

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze, spacebars, meteor-helper

Is there a way to gain access to the Template instance from a global helper and vice versa?

/lib/route.js (with Iron Router):

```
Router.route('/', {name: 'home.view', controller: 'homeController'});
homeController = RouteController.extend({
    template: 'home',
    waitOn: function () {
      Meteor.subscribe("Person", Meteor.userId());
    },
    data: function () {
        // return some data;
    }
});

homeController.helpers({
   templateInstanceHelper: function () {
      // Access a "global" helper here
   }
});
```

/client/helpers.js:

```
Template.helpers("globalHelper", function () {
   // Access the template instance helper here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered defining a global method instead? Instead of registering with Meteor Templates, just define it as

```
globalHelperFunc = function(templateVar) {
   // do work
}
```

Note that this need to be in "lib" folder, so maybe (/lib/helpers.js)

Reference: [Global function for Meteor template helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20681761/global-function-for-meteor-template-helper)

Comment: Thanks. But I need access to the Template instance "Person" subscription data.  I need, for example, the count of the "Person" collection, I need the actual record in some cases, and I need to assign the "Person" record to a #with context within the Template itself.